# Installing Anki on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, anki

I've tried installing anki with "sudo apt install anki" and it won't launch. I get "NameError: name 'QWebEngineView' is not defined." I also have python3-distutils installed.

Also tried to install Anki from their website. After running "sudo make install," Anki manages to run but then I run into this error.

```
Error during startup:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "aqt/main.py", line 45, in _init__
     File "aqt/main.py", line 67, in setupUI
     File "aqt/main.py", line 1374, in setupCrashLog
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:'home/ivan/.local/share/Anki2/crash.log'
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error, the following patch fixed it:

Open `/usr/share/anki/aqt/qt.py`, and change line 13 from:

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
```

to:

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
```

Then save the file and that should do it.

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/anki/+bug/1825722